# Chess Note Taking?

Tags: software

I'd like to start a notebook as I learn more about chess.  I see the interactive diagrams here on stackexchange and think these would be excellent to integrate into my notes.  I'm looking for something that I could use to next through the positions or lines and draw arrows/highlight squares etc in addition to my text notes.  Do you guys have any recommendations on software/apps to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this would help you with your notebook, but most modern GUIs allow for drawing arrows, highlighting squares, etc. For example, Fritz allows you to draw arrows by alt-clicking and highlighting by right-clicking.

If you are looking for something more advanced than this, you might want to take a look at Lucas Chess, which has a feature called 'Director' that allows you to draw various shapes, etc. over the board.

Answer (score 1):

I use LaTeX on overleaf, although its a bit tricky to use. https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Chess_notation

Here is an example of code I did yesterday in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xskak}


\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}




\begin{document}

\input{titlepage}
% \maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Basics:}

This section covers the main basics of the game of chess. It does not go into immense detail.

\subsection{Coordinates}

\subsection{Notation}

\subsection{Rules}

\subsection{Moving the pieces}



\subsubsection{The Queen}

\begin{center}
\newgame
\hyperref[board1]{\textbf{Board 1} - Moves of the Queen}\hypertarget{board1back}{}
\\
\chessboard[
  setfen=8/8/8/8/3Q4/8/8/8 w - - 0 1,
  color=red!50,
  colorbackfields={c5,b6,a7,e3,f2,g1,d1,d2,d3,d5,d6,d7,d8,c3,
                   c4,e4,e5,a1,b2,f6,g7,h8,a4,b4,f4,g4,h4},
  pgfstyle=color,
]
\end{center}

\section{Appendix}
\subsection{Boards}
\end{document}
```

I don't know how better I can explain it without copying and pasting from the link I posted also. [image]

Additionally I use https://lichess.org/editor to generate the FEN and I used the code from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569134/how-can-i-condense-this-code/569137#569137 here. The code examples on Overleaf link initially posted at the top are way simpler though.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestion, I will have to check out Lucas chess as it looks very powerful.  I just found Scid vs PC/Mac which is quite excellent for my needs.

Here's a link for others interested
http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/

The interface is not that intuitive but there are many videos on youtube to learn more.

While it allows all types of annotations I find using these shorctuts are very useful:
You can hold shift and click a square to highlight it
You can hold control and click start square then end square to draw an arrow

Comment: You'd probably also like to check the original Scid, which has been updated quite a few times after Scid vs PC was forked.